# Why is json parse of dynamic link parameters failing?

Tags: javascript, next.js, aws-amplify

I'm trying to pass parms to a dynamic page in an Amplify/NextJS app.

The is a work-in-progress. My goal is to use the passed parms to create a simple page based on 4 parameters passed in the URL invocation.

What's happening is that if I modify the dynamic page file beyond just a few statements, the parameters are no longer being passed - or more probably, are being corrupted somehow.

The dynamic page file (`[id].js`) is very simple:

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router'

export default function Detail() {
    const router = useRouter()
    console.log('router', router)
    const {id, params} = router.query
    console.log('id', id)
    console.log('params', params)
    // const parsed = JSON.parse(params)

}
```

The code that invokes the page is here (note the `JSON.stringify()` in `onClick()`):

```
export function GetDanzanRyuCollection(narration, items, path) {

    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <Text>
                    {narration}
                </Text>
                <Collection
                    type="list"
                    items={items}>
                    {(item, index) => (
                        <View
                            key={index}
                            onClick={() => {
                                let parms = JSON.stringify(item)
                                window.location.href = `./${path}/${item.Number}?params=${parms}`
                            }}>
                            <Card
                                width={"40rem"}
                                variation={"elevated"}
                                key={index}
                                padding="1rem"
                                textAlign={"left"}
                                backgroundColor={"blue.20"}
                                fontSize={"1.5rem"}>
                                <Flex
                                    direction="row"
                                    justifyContent="flex-start"
                                    alignItems="flex-start"
                                    alignContent="flex-start"
                                    gap="1rem">
                                    <Text
                                        width="2.25rem">
                                        {item.Number}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Text
                                        isTruncated="true"
                                        height="3.0rem"
                                        width="15.25rem">
                                        {item.Name}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Text
                                        isTruncated="true"
                                        height="3.0rem"
                                        width="19.25rem">
                                        {item.Description}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Rating
                                        maxValue={1}
                                        value={item.Variations.length}
                                        icon={<ImVideoCamera/>}/>
                                </Flex>
                            </Card>
                        </View>
                    )}
                </Collection>
            </View>
        </>
    )
}
```

Using the unmodified code above, I get the following output in my browser log. In other words, I get the parameters being passed as expected:

[image]

But, if I uncomment the `const parsed = JSON.parse(params)` statement (above), I get this output in the log (notice that `id` and `params` now show as `undefined`):

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong?  Secondly, why are there multiple calls to the `[id].js` file function for a single click?

### Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is likely to contain characters that have special meaning in URLs, so you should encode it:

```
let parms = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(item))
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but I still get the same errors. Thanks tho!